# How to print invoice data correctly to blank spaces of invoice form?

Tags: php, html, printing

I am trying to fill up the blanks of this invoice but the dot-matrix printer does print fields on exactly in their respective box/fields. 
I have used each field margin from upward side in cm and then echoed it in the code using divs. But the printer does not set up the margins and does not align the text leaving text out of the page towards right.

[image]

Comment: why you try to fill in the blanks, while you could as well as print the whole page? positioning the output with x/y and printing into templates might be old-school, but it isn't really difficult either. dot-matrix impact printer in combination with HTML sounds strange to me - because they print raster, alike thermal printers.

Comment: see https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html ...which hints for `lp` or `lpr`.